# Resigning an iOS app (.monotouch-32 symlink)

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, code-signing

I'm attempting to resign an app with a new provisioning profile. My generic steps are:

```
unzip *.ipa
rm *.app/_CodeSignature
cp Payload/*.app/embedded.mobileprovision
codesign -f -s "Cert" --entitlements entitlements.plist Payload/*.app
zip -r Resigned.ipa Payload
```

When I verify the app with verbose output I receive the message

> A sealed resource is missing or invalid

This is followed by a list of `.dll` files in the `.monotouch-32` folder with a message such as:

> "file modified: /foo/bar/Payload/foo.app/.monotouch-32/Xamarin.Forms.Core.dll".

When I inspect the listed `dll`'s, they are all `.symlink`'s to their `.monotouch-64` counterpart. Any specific `.monotouch-32` file is not listed as modified.

Any ideas how I can get around this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might not be your only issue but `zip` requires the use of `-y` for symlinks.

If that does not help then please edit your question to add the commands (and their outputs) used to sign and verify. You should also compare the .ipa (.zip) before and after.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I was facing similar issue. For Xamarin related ipa's its always better o resign the Monotouch and .dll files separately.Please check below command for same

```
sudo codesign -f -s "iPhone Distribution: abcd" --entitlements 
entitlements.plist Payload/myApp.app/.monotouch-32/*.dll
```

Same for Monotouch-64

```
sudo codesign -f -s "iPhone Distribution: abcd" --entitlements 
entitlements.plist Payload/myApp.app/.monotouch-64/*.dll
```

By executing the above commands all the files inside the Payload file will get resigned properly